# Complexity of getting a file C#

Tags: file, complexity-theory, loading

Im thinking of storing a large number of files in a folder and load them into my C# program. The problem I thought about was the performance when loading a file to read from, from a folder that contains very many files. Will the time to load and read from a file be about the same when there is one file in the chosen folder or one million? Does anyone know the complexity? ( O(1), O(n), O(n^2)? )

Comment: How large a number of files are you thinking of, and how large is each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only selected one file, it does not if there is one or a million files, as long as you pick the path correctly.

If you are trying to read all the files,and then search from that, then that is different :P

but if you have the exact file path to it, then no difference